# Get the label mappings from label encoder

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using the following code to map a list of string labels to a list of one-hot-encoded values:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder  
labelEncoder = LabelEncoder()
targets = ["blue","green","blue","blue","green"]    
integerEncoded = labelEncoder.fit_transform(targets)
```

At a later stage I need to know exactly, which string labels are mapped to which integer values.

I.e. I need something like that:

```
integerMapping = GetIntegerMapping(labelEncoder)
```

Where

```
integerMapping["blue"]
```

should return the int value to which all "blue" labels are mapped

and

```
integerMapping["green"]
```

Should return the int value to which all "green" labels are mapped.

How can I get that `integerMapping` dictonary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `LabelEncoder.classes_` and `LabelEncoder.transform()` to get the relationships you're asking for.  The following function should give you what you need.

```
def get_integer_mapping(le):
    '''
    Return a dict mapping labels to their integer values
    from an SKlearn LabelEncoder
    le = a fitted SKlearn LabelEncoder
    '''
    res = {}
    for cl in le.classes_:
        res.update({cl:le.transform([cl])[0]})

    return res
```

#### Example Usage:

```
classes = ['blue', 'green']
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(classes)
integerMapping = get_integer_mapping(le)

integerMapping['blue']  # Returns 0
integerMapping['green']  # Returns 1
```

If you have a very large number of classes, this may not be terribly fast due to the `for` loop, but it should work well for a small number of classes.

#### Update:

Just timed it on a LabelEncoder fit to 10,000 classes.  Here are the results:

```
%timeit get_integer_mapping(le)
1 loop, best of 3: 17.1 s per loop
```

It's actually more performant than I was expecting.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  le is the LabelEncoder instance.  I updated the answer and the docstring.

Comment: I just added example usage to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `classes_` attribute once the label encoder is fitted. The integer used to replace the label value is the index of the label in this array. So you can get the mapping with:

```
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(targets)
integer_mapping = {l: i for i, l in enumerate(le.classes_)}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a dictionary which maps the target and encoded integer

`integerMapping=dict(zip(targets,integerEncoded))`

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple answer:

```py
# helper function to get the mapping between original label and encoded label
def get_label_map(df:pd.DataFrame, label:str):
    """get the mapping between original label and its encoded value
    df: a pandas dataframe with both feature variables and target variable
    label: the name of target variable
    Example:
      df0 = pd.DataFrame({'fea1':[1,2,3,4], 'fea2':['a','b','b','c'], 'target':['cat', 'cat','dog','cat']})
      label = 'target'
      label_map = get_label_map(df=df0, label='target')
    """
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    le = LabelEncoder() # init label encoder
    y_le = le.fit_transform(df[[label]]) # encode target variable
    label_map = dict(zip(df[label], y_le)) # get the mapping between the original labels and encoded labels
    return label_map
```

```py
    Example:
      df0 = pd.DataFrame({'fea1':[1,2,3,4], 'fea2':['a','b','b','c'], 'target':['cat', 'cat','dog','monkey']})

      label_map = get_label_map(df=df0, label='target') # {'cat': 0, 'dog': 1, 'monkey': 2}
```